# Skip widget during traverse event

Tags: java, swt

Given three `Text` widgets inside a `Composite`, as per image, is there a way to skip one during the `SWT.Traverse` event?
The second widget should be focused only via mouse click, or with some other special shortcut.

[image]

Intercepting the `SWT.Traverse` event only allows me to `doit`, or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tab traversal you can use the `setTabList` method of the parent `Composite` to set an array of controls (this also lets you set the order).

```java
public void setTabList (Control [] tabList)
```

> Sets the tabbing order for the specified controls to match the order
> that they occur in the argument list.

Comment: Thanks! Just a little addition: can I know in the target widget, which source widget initiated the traverse event?

Comment: (e.g. in the FocusListener I have no way of tracing the previously focused widget)

Comment: You would probably have to use something like `Display.addFilter` to track focus changes for something iike that.